# Grouping a get items between an timerange

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, grouping

I have this EntityFramework DatabaseContext given:

```
class Worker
{
    int Id,
    string Name,
    ...
    ICollection<Shift> Shifts
}

class Shift
{
    int Id,
    DateTime ShiftStart
    DateTime ShiftEnd
    ...
    Worker Worker
}

class CustomerAction
{
    int Id,
    Worker Worker,
    DateTime ArrivalTime,
    int ActionType
    ...
    string Comment
}
```

Now i want to group all Workers with their Shifts and then get all CustomerActions with ActionType 2 or 4.

Sometimes the Workers dont add their Shifts then all other CustomerActions done by the Worker should listed with empty shift informations.

The Output should look like this:

```
List = 
{
    new Item
    {
        WorkerId = 1, WorkerName = "Worker1" ...
        ShiftId = 1, ShiftStart = 10/1/2017 1:00:00 AM, ShiftEnd = 10/1/2017 5:00:00 AM ...

        // Sorted by ArrivalTime, only in between the ShiftStart / ShiftEnd Range, done by this Worker
        CustomerActions = 
        {
            new CustomerAction { ActionId = 1, ActionType = 4, ArrivalTime = 10/1/2017 1:00:00 AM, Comment = "My comment" }
            new CustomerAction { ActionId = 2, ActionType = 2, ArrivalTime = 10/1/2017 1:30:00 AM, Comment = "Some other comment" }
            new CustomerAction { ActionId = 3, ActionType = 4, ArrivalTime = 10/1/2017 2:00:00 AM, Comment = "No comment" }
        }
    }
    new Item
    {
        WorkerId = 2, WorkerName = "Worker2" ...
        ShiftId = null, ShiftStart = null, ShiftEnd = null ...

        // Sorted by ArrivalTime, done by this Worker, Without an Shift
        CustomerActions = 
        {
            new CustomerAction { ActionId = 4, ActionType = 4, ArrivalTime = 10/2/2017 1:00:00 AM, Comment = "..." }
            new CustomerAction { ActionId = 5, ActionType = 2, ArrivalTime = 10/3/2017 1:30:00 AM, Comment = "..." }
            new CustomerAction { ActionId = 6, ActionType = 4, ArrivalTime = 10/4/2017 2:00:00 AM, Comment = "..." }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by group workers? group them by what?

Comment: For example group workers by Id. Each worker can have multiple shifts in each shift can be multiple customerActions observed by this worker. In the desired output you can get an idea how it should look like.

Comment: You can group by Hour (a number between 0 to 23).  with a modular number on start time.  GroupBy( x => (int)(x.myDate.Hour/4)  which will group by start time 0:00 - 4: 00, 4:00 - 8:00, 8:00 - 12:00, ...   What you can also do is to subtract 1 from hour so you would get 7:00 - 11:00.

Comment: @jdweng I thought about this but I don't think this will work. The ShiftStart and ShiftEnd aren't bound to fixed Hours. Shifts can also span to the next day.

Comment: You really only need start time to group.  Adding or Subtracting a number will handle a shift that goes past midnight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you don't need grouping. Instead, you need to expand, for each workers shift the actions worked upon. The code below should point you to the right direction:

```
var registeredShifts = dbContext.Workers
    .SelectMany(w => w.Shifts.Select(s => new
    {
        WorkerId = w.Id,
        WorkerName = w.Name,
        ShiftId = s.Id,
        ShiftStart = s.ShiftStart,
        ShiftEnd = s.ShiftEnd,
        CustomerActions =  dbContext.CustomerActions
            .Where(a => a.Worker.Id == w.Id && 
                    a.ArrivalTime >= s.ShiftStart &&
                    a.ArrivalTime <= s.ShiftEnd &&
                    (a.ActionType == 2 || a.ActionType == 4))
            .ToList()
    }))
```

**EDIT**: To the same results for actions outside the registered shifts you'll have to use grouping.

```
var outsideShifts = dbContrxt.CustomerActions
    .Where(a => a.ActionType == 2 || a.ActionType == 4)
    .Where(a => a.Worker.Shifts.All(s => a.ArrivalTime < s.ShiftStart ||
                                         a.ArrivalTime > s.ShiftEnd))
    .GroupBy(a => new 
    { 
        WorkerId = a.Worker.Id,
        WorkerName = a.Worker.Name
    })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        WorkerId = g.Key.WorkerId,
        WorkerName = g.Key.WorkerName,
        ShiftId = null,
        ShiftStart = null,
        ShiftEnd = null,
        CustomerActions = g.ToList()
    });
```

Finally, to get the required data, `Union()` the results above:

```
var result = registeredShifts.Union(outsideShifts);
return result.ToArray();
```

Comment: You are correct I didn't need an grouping. Your answer was helpfull! I have a last problem with this query. Sometimes the Workes forget to add their Shift. If there is no Shift the ShiftId, ShiftStart, ShiftEnd should be Empty and all other CustomerActions (not in any shift time) by this Worker should be listed

Comment: @ParadoxSeki, please see the edit; I should give you an idea how to tackle the second part of the query.